# The controls of my game freeze after the first keypress with int 16h / ah=1

Tags: assembly, keyboard, x86-16, bios

I am coding a game in assembly 8086. I fixed the issue when the game didn't open, but I can't fix the controls.

The <kbd>ESC</kbd> key works. When I press it, it goes to *_QUIT* function, but if any other key was pressed before that, the controls freeze and don't react on any key.

Is there something wrong with my function?

I tried to change the `AL` register to `AH`, but it didn't work.

```
_KEYCHECK:
        mov ah,01h
        int 16h

        cmp al,1Bh      ;ESC
        je _QUIT
        cmp al,48h      ;UP
        je _PLAYER.UP
        cmp al,50h      ;DOWN
        je _PLAYER.DOWN
        cmp al,4Bh      ;LEFT
        je _PLAYER.LEFT
        cmp al,4Dh      ;RIGHT
        je _PLAYER.RIGHT
        ret
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your *_KEYCHECK* function is using the BIOS.ReadKeyboard**Status** function.

It will inform you about the availability of a keyboard key by setting the ZeroFlag (ZF) if no key is available, or by clearing the ZeroFlag if a key is waiting. In the latter case you will also receive the key's ASCII code and scancode.
**The important thing here is that a key that is reported available stays in the keyboard buffer**. The info that you get in `AL` and `AH` is just a preview not the actual key (in a sense). This explains your observation:

> ... but if any other key was pressed before that the controls frees ...

The solution is to remove the key from the keyboard buffer. That's what BIOS.ReadKeyboard**Character** does. If a key is waiting it will return very quickly with the key removed from the buffer. If no key is available it will wait until one comes available and then return with that key removed from the buffer.

```
_KEYCHECK:
    mov     ah, 01h     ; BIOS.ReadKeyboardStatus
    int     16h         ; -> AX ZF
    jz      NoKeyAvailable
    mov     ah, 00h     ; BIOS.ReadKeyboardCharacter
    int     16h         ; -> AX

    cmp     al, 1Bh      ;ESC
    je      _QUIT
    cmp     ah, 48h      ;UP
    je      _PLAYER.UP
    cmp     ah, 50h      ;DOWN
    je      _PLAYER.DOWN
    cmp     ah, 4Bh      ;LEFT
    je      _PLAYER.LEFT
    cmp     ah, 4Dh      ;RIGHT
    je      _PLAYER.RIGHT
NoKeyAvailable:
    ret
```

Please note:

- You didn't actually inspect the ZeroFlag to find out if the info in `AL` and `AH` was valid.
- The number 1Bh (ESC) is an ASCII code and has to be checked from `AL` but all the other codes 48h (UP), 50h (DOWN), 4Bh (LEFT), and 4Dh (RIGHT) are scancodes and thus have to be checked from `AH`.

Comment: Thank you! Now I can control my player.

Answer (score 1):

You are using int 16h,1.
As you can see [here](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_16-1.html), special keys(like arrows) has a value called scan code and the scan code is returned in ah. Try

```
        mov ah,01h
        int 16h
        cmp al,1Bh      ;ESC
        je _QUIT
        cmp ah,48h      ;UP
        je _PLAYER.UP
        cmp ah,50h      ;DOWN
        je _PLAYER.DOWN
        cmp ah,4Bh      ;LEFT
        je _PLAYER.LEFT
        cmp ah,4Dh      ;RIGHT
        je _PLAYER.RIGHT
```

If thats not working, I suggest you to debug and check if the problem not in another place(For example try to print something under _PLAYER.UP)